# Как запустить content script после загрузки всех скриптов сайта?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Мне нужно изменить значение инпута, загружающегося из js, на сайте

```
document.getElementById("name").value= "Jack";
```

И в консоли мне выдает ошибку `Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Можно ли как-то дождаться загрузки элемента и выполнить content script?

manifest.json

```
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "extension",
    "description": "change value ",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    },
    
    "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "/js/changeval.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
   }
 ],   
"permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]  
}
```

changeval.js

```
document.getElementById("name").value= "Jack";
```

Comment: Попробуйте MutationObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver , https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer — то есть понаблюдайте за добавлением элементов, пока не добавится нужный, затем запустите функцию с основным кодом.

Answer (score 0):

DOMContentLoaded генерируется после того как DOM уже будет сформирован:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("name").value= "Jack"
});
```

Можно передать туда функцию, и в ней выполнять всю логику:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunc);

function myFunc() {
   document.getElementById("name").value= "Jack"   
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("name").value= "Jack"
}
```

Вариант с `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" ...` более предпочтителен, так как не ждет загрузки внешних ресурсов, таких как картинки  и стили, в отличии от `window.onload`

Также есть вариант `addEventListener("load", () => {}`, который используется для отслеживания полностью загруженной страницы. Работает как и `window.onload`, но имеет преимущества addEventListener-a, с помощью которого можно повесить несколько обработчиков на один элемент, и также удалить обработчики используя `removeEventListener`

Comment: Input загружается из скрипта, поэтому DOMContentLoaded не помогает.
Window.onload выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at window.onload, уже все эти способы перепробовал, в манифесте менял run_at, ничего не помогает

Comment: приложите весь код, пожалуйста

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: покажите где формируется инпут

Comment: он формируется на стороннем сайте, я пишу расширение для браузера

Comment: как это должно помочь?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917047/how-to-get-a-content-script-to-load-after-a-pages-javascript-has-executed может быть это поможет

Comment: Все равно ошибка Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: а если document вывести в консоль? есть ли он?

Comment: Да, document выводится

Comment: тогда может быть там нету элемента с таким айдишником? Вы выводили его в консоль?

Comment: Если ставить setTimeout, то все работает, значение меняется. Я понаблюдал и заметил, что при переходе на нужный url страница не обновляется, просто меняется адрес, и контент скрипт не загружается, грузит только после ручного обновления. Возможно это мешает?

Comment: Например, на гитхабе так же